# javascript error split is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to search my html for class `ardiv` and then search this class for `span`.
Then i want to get `value` from this span element using `split` function, but i am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: paranula.split is not a function

```js
    function hledat() {

 var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("ardiv");

 for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var para = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("span");
  var paranula = para[0];
  console.log(paranula);
  var parasplit = paranula.split(">");
  console.log(parasplit[1]);
 }

    }

    hledat();
```

```html
<span class="hiddenid">188</span>
```

Comment: Why are you using the `split` function and not `paranula.id`? `split` is for splitting strings not selecting/filtering elements or fetching attributes.

Comment: Your code snippet works, so I am assuming that the `0`th element returned by `getElementByTagName` is not the span you are expecting. Try narrowing down on the selector; maybe an `id` would be a better approach.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now, the use of `ID` was confusing. Instead of parsing the span HTML as a string, just use `parseInt( paranula.innerText )` and that will get the id as a number.

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector('.ardiv .hiddenid').textContent);`

Comment: ´paranula´ contains this ´<span class="hiddenid">188</span>´ so i wanted to split it twice. First using ´.split(">")´ ,second time using ´.split("<")´, that should end up with string containg only value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paranula is HTMLElement - kind of JS object, not a string. To access it as a string, use

```
var parasplit = paranula.outerHTML.split(">");
```

But if all you need it to take "188" from provided example, use

```
var result= paranula.innerHTML
```

The ID of element is other thing - with element like this

```
<span id="188" class="hiddenid"></span>
```

you could get "188" with

```
var result= paranula.id
```

Comment: Thank you, the ´var result = paranula.innerHTML´ worked.